# Prevent refactoring mistakes with mapping libraries

Tags: c#, automapper, objectmapper, object-object-mapping

Given

```
class A { string Name {get;set;} }
class B { string Name {get;set;} }
```

I then use automapper to translate between A and B. Later, I rename `A.Name` to `A.MyName`:

```
class A { string MyName {get;set;} }
class B { string Name {get;set;} }
```

This will break my mapping, because of implicit configuration. Implicit configuration implicitly create a relationship between `A` and `B`. Refactoring algorithm do not recognize this relationship thus producing a break.

What mappers solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think there is one, you have two distinctly different types and you will need to define how they are mapped.  The best you can hope for is a strongly typed mapping so when you refactor the code will generate errors at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AutoMapper, assuming that you have handled all properties in your mappings (by either mapping them or explicitly ignoring them), `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` is the way to manage this problem.

As the [documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration-validation) says:

> Executing this code produces an AutoMapperConfigurationException, with a descriptive message. **AutoMapper checks to make sure that every single Destination type member has a corresponding type member on the source type.**

Thus after you have refactored your classes, there will not be a mapping defined, and the test will fail.

You can put it in a unit test, or in your startup code if you don't have any tests.

Comment: This solution only works when you call this method in e.g. a unit test for all configurations. A solution on build-time would be a bit better.

Comment: Personally I don't mind what developers do locally, because *it's what gets checked in that counts*. If you have a gated build process where all the tests have to pass before the checkin succeeds, you can prevent these from being checked in. Or if you prefer you can let it break the build and apportion blame.

Answer (score 0):

Use an interface `interface ABcommon { string Name {get;set;} }` and class A and B implements it. Rename will work.

Comment: There is no common interface once the class A has been refactored to use MyName.

Comment: The point of the interface is to act as an adapter between the classes, routing `IA.Name` to `A.MyName`.

Comment: This will not work since the property names are different between classes A and B. Therefore, they cannot implement both interfaces.

Comment: @Adam Carr: If you create the ABcommon interface and tell the program that A and B implements it, than all changes will be made on the interface and the implementing classes. VS 2013 lets you rename the implementation and reflects the change to the interface and the other imeplenting classes!

Comment: @PeterKrassoi yes that is valid but I believe the question was how to automatically refactor.  This would force all implementing classes to use the interface. The OP stated that only the property in class A was being renamed.  So A.MyName and B.Name would be the implementation and the interface would be incorrect.

Comment: @Adam Carr: Exactly, I *do want* to map properties X and Y with same type, but different name. Implementing an interface explicitly prevents this from happening, and therefore not a solution.